# HTML5 web storage integer becomes NaN

Tags: javascript, html, nan, web-storage

Can anyone explain why last line results in NaN? 'userScore' is an object of a span element and similar operations work perfectly fine when I don't implement the localStorage part. Many thanks in advance!

```
    var score;
    score = 20 - (parseInt(turnNr.innerHTML) - bricks.length / 2) * 
    1.2;
    if (score >= 0.5) {
        score = Math.round(score);
    } else {
        score = 0;
    }

    if (localStorage.totalScore) {
       localStorage.totalScore = parseInt(localStorage.totalScore) + 
        score;
    } else {
        localStorage.totalScore = score;
    }
    userScore.innerHTML = localStorage.totalScore;
```

Comment: That's not how local storage works. [Read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

Comment: Use localStorage.getItem() to retrieve date from localstorage.

Comment: So `parseInt(localStorage.totalScore)` yields `NaN`? What debugging have you done? What values do your variables have?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan What exactly do you refer to?

Comment: @PetroGordiyevich [That's not necessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Basic_concepts) (unless there's a potential collision with the method names)

Comment: @Bergi, basically I've just used alerts. And yes, it yields a NaN when I alert it as well. Not sure which other variables you mean.

Comment: So what is the value (and typeof) of `localStorage.totalScore`? If you're storing the string `NaN` once, you won't get away from that of course.

Comment: @Bergi, just did three alerts:     alert(localStorage.totalScore);
    alert(localStorage.totalScore.value);
    alert(typeof localStorage.totalScore); nr 1: NaN, nr2: undefined, nr3: string

Comment: @bergi the part where data are retrieved via getItem and set via setItem? It may not be necessary, but that's the API.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I guess that's just because the proxy-like capabilities fit hardly into the MDN documentation format. Still, it is how it works (…as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code cannot recover from errors. Once you have stored `"NaN"` in localStorage, it never will go away when the code is executed. That's because `if (localStorage.totalScore)` will run even when there's an invalid value.

You'll want to change your code to

```
if (parseInt(localStorage.totalScore)) { // NaN is falsy and will be ignored
   localStorage.totalScore = parseInt(localStorage.totalScore) + score;
} else {
    localStorage.totalScore = score;
}
userScore.innerHTML = localStorage.totalScore;
```

Comment: Ah, I see, that's it! Tested and it worked perfectly!  Many thanks mate!